# Listview Volley with Fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I want to show `listview` in fragment, but I got an error.

This is my **MainActivity**:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
private List<Produk> produkList = new ArrayList<Produk>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private ServerRequest serverRequest;
JSONArray member = null;
private static final String url = "http://10.0.3.2:808/Koen_CI/index.php/daftar_barang_control";

public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    loadPreferences();
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    Log.d("TAG", "TEST1");
    listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
    Log.d("TAG", "TEST2");
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), produkList);
    Log.d("TAG", "TEST3");
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    Log.d("TAG", "TEST4");

    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest produkReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d("TAG", response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();
                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Produk produk = new Produk();
                            produk.setNamaProduk(obj.getString("nama_produk"));
                            produk.setHargaProduk(obj.getString("harga_produk"));
                            produk.setFotoProduk(obj.getString("foto_produk"));
                            Log.d("TAG", "TAG : " + produk.getNamaProduk());    

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            produkList.add(produk);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d("TAG", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(produkReq);
}
```

I got this error:
java.lang.**NullPointerException**

I debug with Log.d, error line is in:

```
adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), produkList);
```

what is it?

this is my **CustomListAdapter**

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Produk> produkItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

 public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Produk> produkItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.produkItems = produkItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return produkItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return produkItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.namaProduk);
    TextView rating = (TextView)         convertView.findViewById(R.id.hargastokProduk);

    // getting movie data for the row
    Produk p = produkItems.get(position);

    // thumbnail image
    thumbNail.setImageUrl(p.getFotoProduk(), imageLoader);

    // title
    title.setText(p.getNamaProduk());

    // rating
    rating.setText("Harga: " + p.getHargaProduk());

    return convertView;
}

}
```

Logcat:

> 02-27 04:45:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4739): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-27 04:45:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4739): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.koenb_fashion_fix/com.koenb_fashion_fix.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   02-27 04:45:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
>   02-27 04:45:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
>   02-27 04:45:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
>   02-27 04:45:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4739):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
>   02-27 04:45:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4739):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   02-27 04:45:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4739):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   02-27 04:45:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>   02-27 04:45:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4739):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   02-27 04:45:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4739):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   02-27 04:45:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4739):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   02-27 04:45:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4739):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   02-27 04:45:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4739):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   02-27 04:45:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4739): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   02-27 04:45:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4739):     at com.koen_bfashion.image.CustomListAdapter.(CustomListAdapter.java:22)
>   02-27 04:45:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4739):     at com.koenb_fashion_fix.Home_Fragment.onCreate(Home_Fragment.java:72)
>   02-27 04:45:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4739):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:796)
>   02-27 04:45:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4739):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
>   02-27 04:45:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4739):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
>   02-27 04:45:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4739):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
>   02-27 04:45:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4739):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5017)
>   02-27 04:45:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2032)
>   02-27 04:45:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4739):     ... 11 more

Comment: It is not getting activity. getActivity() is returning null

Comment: yup, and how i fix that?

Comment: @XenixPutraSasongko: why not adding full log with question ?

Comment: you mean the LogCat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Calling `findViewById` method using `getActivity()`  means accessing view from layout of Activity in which `Fragment` is added.

Use `rootView` object in `onCreateView` to access views from layout of Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work sir, its still give me error java.lang.nullpointerexception.
i have added listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list); in onCreateView method.

the error is still same, on the adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), produkList);

Comment: @XenixPutraSasongko: probably some other issues also present so please show full log with question

Comment: @XenixPutraSasongko: What is line number `22` in `CustomListAdapter.java` ?

Comment: ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

i don't know, that code i get from example imagelistview with volley..

Comment: @XenixPutraSasongko: just comment `ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();` line and post link from which you have found this line\

Comment: i got that example from here: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/ . if i comment that code i got error 'imageLoader cannot be resolved to a variable'

Comment: @XenixPutraSasongko: Change `ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();` to `ImageLoader imageLoader;`

Comment: ok, thats work. but the error now in line listView.setAdapter(adapter);. give me java.lang.NullPointerException again..

Comment: @XenixPutraSasongko: Show `AppController` class

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, its work now. when we discuss i find the same problem on stackoverflow. and i follow it. and its work now.. you are awesome sirr!!